# Removing wildcards from code

Tags: perl, bash

I've got a series of lines with "*"

```
*foobar.com*
*foo*bar.com
http://foobar.com/*
*.foobar.com/foobar/*
*.foobar.org/*
*/foo.bar.com/*
*/foobar/?*
*_foobar.*
*&foobar?*
```

Using Bash or Perl, I just want to remove the "*" so.. the following should end up like,

```
foobar.com
foobar.com
http://foobar.com/
.foobar.com/foobar/
.foobar.org/
/foo.bar.com/
/foobar/?
_foobar.
&foobar?
```

Answer (score 7):

From bash:

```
tr -d '*' <infile >outfile
```

perl:

```
perl -pwe'tr/*//d' <infile >outfile
```

or inplace:

```
perl -i -pwe'tr/*//d' filename
```

Comment: ++ for using tr instead of a regex.

Comment: @user349418: if it's perfect, check the checkmark next to it to make it the accepted answer